# Share content across Markdown files

Tags: php, markdown, dry

I've got a set of six Markdown tutorials written for different programming languages. The problem is that the files often share whole paragraphs of content, so now we have the same content represented in six places. This means that keeping everything in sync after updating is really frustrating.

Is there a way to only store the paragraph data in one place? Currently, we are processing the Markdown file and returning HTML at the time the user requests the page, although we could change that with a good solution.

Comment: Is the content on your pages generated by PHP?

Comment: Yes, the content's generated by PHP.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly straight forwards to achieve.

I would add some custom markup to your markdown files for where the common text should be inserted. Something like:

```
{{commonText1}}
```

Where `commonText1` was the core of a file name (e.g. `commonText1.MD` or some such).

Then amend the PHP that translates the MD to HTML so that it first does a pass through the text looking for your markup, reading the appropriate common file and inserting the text. You would then resume your normal translation.

Another possibility would be for the translator PHP not just to change the output but also change the input file. In this case, you would end up with two custom tags with the common text inserted between them - so you start off as above and end up with:

```
... blah blah ....
{{?commonText1}}
This is the common text, inserted so that reading the source text file still makes sense
{{/commonText1}}
... more blah ...
```

I suggest that this would be useful if your authors need to see the common text in place for clarity. Although at any time, the  common text may be out of date, it would still help authors. You could also have a simple updater script that would check and update the common text.

Even an amateur PHP programmer should be able to make these changes and test them in a couple of days at most.

Hope this makes sense, if not, leave a comment and I will try to improve the answer.